# css target first li in a div of many divs

Tags: css, css-selectors

so I have been trying all this stuff with `first-child` and everything and none seem to be working. If I have a div set up as such:

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="thing">
        abd
    </div>
    <div class="thing">

    </div>
    <div class="thing">
        123
    </div>
    <div class="thing">
        <li class="list" goal="target">
            1
        </li>
    </div>
    <div class="thing">
        <li class="list">
            2
        </li>
    </div>
    <div class="thing">
        <li class="list">
            3
        </li>
    </div>
    <div class="thing">
        <li class="list">
            4
        </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

**what line of css that will be able to target only the first `li` element in the `.content` `div` (the one with the attribute `goal="target"`)**

now this can be fairly messy and there can be anywhere from 0 to 10 `div`s without a `li` before the first that contains one.

I have tried nearly anything with `first-child`, but it always targets every single `li` because they are in `div`s.

[here is a jsfiddle if you want to try things](http://jsfiddle.net/apjhA/)

Comment: So you want to apply CSS to only the `li` element which has an attribute `goal="target"`  ?

Comment: no. that was so you guys could see which I was talking about. that's my bad...I want to be able to target the first `li` in that specific div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CSS the format is `grandparent parent element child`... and `:nth-child` gives you the element the number specified down, so for your case that would be

```
.content .thing:nth-child(4) li {
   /* CSS goes here */
}
```

In your example `.content` is the grandparent, `.thing` (the fourth one) is the parent, and of course the `li` is the element. Spaces are required for distinguishing in between levels in CSS.

[Here is a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6xMaK/)

**Edit** Without it being hard coded **it's impossible** to select the first `li` no matter who it's parent is without javascript.

Here is a jQuery fix:

```
$('.content').find("li").eq(0).css({ /* CSS goes here */});
```

Here is a straight javascript fix:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('li')[0];
elems.style.property="value";
```

Comment: " there can be anywhere from 0 to 10 divs without a li before the first that contains one."

Comment: I added a javascript and jQuery fix you can choose from. Doing what you want with pure CSS is impossible

Comment: thank you! that worked perfectly! too bad about the raw css though

Answer (score 0):

OK first things first, `goal` is an invalid attribute so you shouldn't be using it. If you need custom attributes you should be using [data-attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=HTML/Global_attributes#data-%2a)

In order to target an element by attribute you should be using an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS/Attribute_selectors) in your case the following selector would work.

```
li[goal="target"]{

    /* Your styles go here.*/    

}
```

Comment: Target was just so we knew which one he wanted to select

Comment: That should have been specified in the question. No need for the downvote. I had to click reveal to show the comment. If that is the case there are no current css selectors that will match the query.